# Mod Security log monitoring

Tags: apache-2.2, logging, mod-security

Is there a web based log management utility present for Mod Security? As parsing the logs of Mod Security is a big headache. I can only see traditional log monitoring systems but not any, which is intended for mod-security logs analysing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try Splunk ?

Splunk for ModSecurity provides searches, reports and dashboards for the famous apache module ModSecurity from Trustwave SpiderLabs.

Comment: Actually its not free, thats the problem. Otherwise its best..

Comment: How about graylog2 ?